# Using Google Adwords API in PHP

Tags: php, api, soap, google-ads-api

Hi there I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

Basically I am trying to use the trafficEstimatorService in order to retrieve how much traffic a keyword that is entered through a HTML generates.

I have an idea of how to make it work but I am totally new to using the google API.

Firstly would I create the form in php and perform a GET request on the trafficEstimator url with the keywords in the form as parameters?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add any code you have tried and is not working?  Stackoverflow is intended to help answer specific questions and this question needs a bit more specificity.

Answer (score 5):

I found that the hardest part of getting started was the Oauth Authentication. Ewan Hemming's tutorial on the subject helped me out a lot: http://www.ewanheming.com/adwords-api-oauth-tutorial

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib 
It's a php client library including examples on how to do things + a video which is a very good and detailed starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you already tried to follow [Make Your First API Call](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call) and video with talk through instead of walkthrough of the steps and you felt confused and unclear, then [here is step by step tutorial](https://razbakov.com/google-ads-php/) for you.